# The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Abyss\Desktop\Test\filename.txt' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

I have tried most of the solutions in stackoverflow and I haven't been able to find the solution so I need to ask here.

Below is my code:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace ConfigurationTest
{
    class Program
    {
        ////Approach On Sending Email
        public static void GetConfigurationValue()
        {
            var AttactmentDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AttactmentDirectory"];
            var ReceiverEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReceiverEmail"];
            var host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
            var port = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"];
            var SenderEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderEmail"];
            var SenderPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderPassword"];
            var sentDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sentDirectory"];

            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(AttactmentDirectory);

                foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles("*.*"))
                {
                    if (file.Exists)
                    {

                        if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name).Equals("itemname1"))
                        {                        
                            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                            //declare SmtpClient
                            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
                            SmtpServer.Host = host;
                            SmtpServer.Port = Int32.Parse(port);
                            SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SenderEmail, SenderPassword);
                            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;

                            mail.From = new MailAddress(SenderEmail);
                            mail.To.Add(ReceiverEmail);
                            mail.Subject = "itemname1";
                            mail.Body = "";
                            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file.FullName));
                            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                            if (mail.Attachments != null)
                            {
                                mail.Attachments.Clear();
                                mail.Attachments.Dispose();
                            }
                            mail.Dispose();
                            mail = null;
                            SmtpServer.Dispose();
                            SmtpServer = null;
                            Console.WriteLine("itemname1 mail sent");

                           
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name).Equals("itemname2"))
                            {
                                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                                //declare SmtpClient
                                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
                                SmtpServer.Host = host;
                                SmtpServer.Port = Int32.Parse(port);
                                SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SenderEmail, SenderPassword);
                                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;

                                mail.From = new MailAddress(SenderEmail);
                                mail.To.Add(ReceiverEmail);
                                mail.Subject = "itemname2";
                                mail.Body = "";
                                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file.FullName));

                                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                                if (mail.Attachments != null)
                                {
                                    mail.Attachments.Clear();
                                    mail.Attachments.Dispose();
                                }
                                mail.Dispose();
                                SmtpServer.Dispose();
                                SmtpServer = null;
                                Console.WriteLine("itemname2 mail sent");
                                
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                                //declare SmtpClient
                                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
                                SmtpServer.Host = host;
                                SmtpServer.Port = Int32.Parse(port);
                                SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SenderEmail, SenderPassword);
                                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;

                                mail.From = new MailAddress(SenderEmail);
                                mail.To.Add(ReceiverEmail);
                                mail.Subject = "itemname3 Ahead";
                                mail.Body = "";
                                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file.FullName));

                                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                                if (mail.Attachments != null)
                                {
                                    mail.Attachments.Clear();
                                    mail.Attachments.Dispose();
                                }
                                mail.Dispose();
                                SmtpServer.Dispose();
                                SmtpServer = null;
                                Console.WriteLine("itemname3  mail sent");
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Mail Send");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(AttactmentDirectory);

            foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
            {
                file.Delete();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("---- Sending Email -----");
            GetConfigurationValue();
        }
    }
}
```

The error will be on this line:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(AttactmentDirectory);

foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete();
}
```

I have tried disposing of the SMTPClient and MailMessage that used the file. It still doesn't work. I've tried commenting everything about SMTPClient and MailMessage and it works just fine so it shouldn't be the cause of the FileInfo and DirectoryInfo.

Comment: To start with, don't dispose, use a using start everywhere, on everything that supports it

Comment: Check if mail is sent and then delete the file instead deleting all files using loop. like if(SmtpServer.Send(mail)) File.Delete(file.FullName); or instead of attaching as file, read the file as stream and use that stream as attachment.

Comment: Side note: `file.Exists` will always be true. Unless you have some very unlikely concurrency with another program deleting files. And then file.Exists is a false security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably in

```
mail.Attachments.Clear();
mail.Attachments.Dispose();
```

When you first Clear() it the underlying attachments will not be Disposed.

You probably don't need the Clear() at all, but otherwise do it *after* the Dispose().

```
mail.Attachments.Dispose();
//mail.Attachments.Clear();     // can't Clear after Dispose
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution works. The best solution is removing the Clear(). I tried to put the clear but it says that I cannot clear because it has been disposed of. Thank you